# problem extracting JSON data from server PHP array

Tags: javascript, php, json, wordpress

I am trying to extract a stock price from a JSON response created by a PHP file on my server. I have described 2 tests below, Test 1 extracts the JSON data from a file successfully, Test 2. getting the JSON data from aPHP script on the server results in errors. I have worked on this for ages so any help in getting a solution would be hugely appreciated, many thanks.

I am using Wordpress and Woody Universal Snippets on the client, ultimately I will integrate the code into a datatables script once working.

Test 1. get the JSON data from a text file on the server works 100% below

```
<script>

var ourRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
ourRequest.open("GET", "../../Editor-PHP-1.9.0/controllers/ajax_stock_holdings_json1.txt");

//ourRequest.open("GET", "../../Editor-PHP-1.9.0/controllers/ajax_stock_holdings1.php");
//ourRequest.open("GET", "https://dividendlook.co.uk/Editor-PHP-1.9.0/controllers/ajax_stock_holdings1.php");   
ourRequest.onload = function() {
console.log(ourRequest.responseText);
    var ourDataJSON = JSON.parse(ourRequest.responseText);
}
ourRequest.send();  
</script>
```

JSON File ajax_stock_holdings_json1.txt

```
[
  {
    "symbol": "CTY.LSE",
    "price" : "430"
  }
]
```

Test 2. Fails
comment out line

```
ourRequest.open("GET", "../../Editor-PHP-1.9.0/controllers/ajax_stock_holdings_json1.txt");
```

uncomment line

```
ourRequest.open("GET", "../../Editor-PHP-1.9.0/controllers/ajax_stock_holdings1.php");
```

run local client script below

```
<script>

var ourRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
//ourRequest.open("GET", "../../Editor-PHP-1.9.0/controllers/ajax_stock_holdings_json1.txt");

ourRequest.open("GET", "../../Editor-PHP-1.9.0/controllers/ajax_stock_holdings1.php");
//ourRequest.open("GET", "https://dividendlook.co.uk/Editor-PHP-1.9.0/controllers/ajax_stock_holdings1.php");   
ourRequest.onload = function() {
console.log(ourRequest.responseText);
    var ourDataJSON = JSON.parse(ourRequest.responseText);
}
ourRequest.send();  
</script>
```

Server PHP File

```
<?php
 /* Loads the WordPress environment and template */
require( '../../wp-blog-header.php' );

global $current_user;
wp_get_current_user();

// DataTables PHP library
include( "../lib/DataTables.php" );

$json_array = array();
$stock_id = 709; // CTY.LSE

try {
    $pdo = new PDO(strtolower($sql_details['type']) . ":host=" . $sql_details['host'] . ";dbname=" . $sql_details['db'], $sql_details['user'], $sql_details['pass']);
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    echo "Connected successfully" . "\n\n"; 
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }

$result = $pdo->query("SELECT id, symbol, name, price FROM dm_stocks WHERE id = $stock_id");
        foreach ($result as $row) {

                echo "" . $row['id'] . "";
                echo " : " . $row['symbol'] . "";
                echo " : " . $row['name'] . "";
                echo " : " . $row['price'] . "\n";

        array_push( $json_array, array('symbol'=>$row['symbol'], 'price'=>$row['price'] ) );
        }

echo json_encode($json_array); 

?>
```

**Results are** 
ajax_stock_holdings1.php 
Network Response

```
Connected successfully

709 : CTY.LSE : City of London Investment Trust Plc : 405.5
[{"symbol":"CTY.LSE","price":"405.5"}]
```

Console Log

```
JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed, version 1.4.1
(index):294 Connected successfully

709 : CTY.LSE : City of London Investment Trust Plc : 405.5
[{"symbol":"CTY.LSE","price":"405.5"}]
VM2786:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token C in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at XMLHttpRequest.ourRequest.onload ((index):295)
```

Uncommenting line using full path to PHP

```
ourRequest.open("GET", "https://dividendlook.co.uk/Editor-PHP-1.9.0/controllers/ajax_stock_holdings1.php");
```

results in the following error

Console displays

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://dividendlook.co.uk/Editor-PHP-1.9.0/controllers/ajax_stock_holdings1.php' from origin 'https://www.dividendlook.co.uk' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I have tried configuring HTTP Headers plugin to no avail, this may be down to an infinite number of configuration options, knowing which if any will clear my errors.

I have added code to my server PHP file to fix the Access-Control-Allow-Origin problem to as follows :-

```
<?php
 /* Loads the WordPress environment and template */
require( '../../wp-blog-header.php' );

global $current_user;
wp_get_current_user();

// DataTables PHP library
include( "../lib/DataTables.php" );

// HTTP Header 

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://dividendlook.co.uk');

$json_array = array();
$stock_id = 709; // CTY.LSE

...etc as before
```

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.4.1:2 JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed, version 1.4.1
(index):1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://dividendlook.co.uk/Editor-PHP-1.9.0/controllers/ajax_stock_holdings1.php' from origin 'https://www.dividendlook.co.uk' has been blocked by CORS policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'https://divdendook.co.uk' that is not equal to the supplied origin.
generic-no-float.css:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
```

substituting following line to PHP file instead of previous with sitename

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

results in error

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.4.1:2 JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed, version 1.4.1
(index):294 Connected successfully

709 : CTY.LSE : City of London Investment Trust Plc : 405.5
[{"symbol":"CTY.LSE","price":"405.5"}]
(index):1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token C in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at XMLHttpRequest.ourRequest.onload ((index):295)
generic-no-float.css:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
```

I have added the following code to the end of .htaccess which has fixed the CORS policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' problem, now the error is

'''
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.4.1:2 JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed, version 1.4.1
(index):290 ourRequest.responseText >>>>>:[{"symbol":"CTY.LSE","price":"405.5"}]:<<<<
generic-no-float.css:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
'''

The JSON is however being read by the client script OK

New client script

```
<script>    
var ourRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
ourRequest.open("GET", "https://dividendlook.co.uk/Editor-PHP-1.9.0/controllers/ajax_stock_holdings1.php"); 
ourRequest.onload = function() {
console.log("ourRequest.responseText >>>>>:"+ourRequest.responseText+":<<<<");
}
ourRequest.send();  
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your server ,PHP. Add those required headers. Browsers reject response from different origins. To get this work, Set the Access-Control-Allow-Origin to '*'. This was any request from any origin gets served a response.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, it makes sense what is the command to set Access-Control-Allow-Origin to '*'. in the server PHP file. Thanks Colin

Comment: CeoFred Is this code snippet an example of what you mean ?? , I will try and add the required code https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Server-Side_Access_Control

Comment: CeoFred I have added more detail to the call in response to your suggestion thanks Colin

Comment: added to .htaccess Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "https://www.dividendlook.co.uk"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "GET,POST,OPTIONS,DELETE,PUT" I have shown the results in the main question above thanks Colin